# "Per request" activation context ... without request

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject.web.mvc, application-start, ninject.web

I have a repository that needs to be created per request. Now there is a singleton caching object that needs to use that repository to fill itself with data, but this object is initialized in the Application_Start event, therefore there is not request context.

Which would be the best way of accomplish this with Ninject?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As current `HttpContext` is missing on app startup (in IIS7 integration mode) Ninject will definitely treat object binded `InRequestScope` as it would be in `InTransientScope` when you try to inject dependency on app startup. As we can see in Ninject's (2.2) source code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Scope callbacks for standard scopes.
/// </summary>
public class StandardScopeCallbacks
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the callback for transient scope.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly Func<IContext, object> Transient = ctx => null;

    #if !NO_WEB
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the callback for request scope.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly Func<IContext, object> Request = ctx => HttpContext.Current;
    #endif
}
```

`HttpContext.Current` will be `null` at app startup, so the `InRequestScope` binded object will be treated on app startup the same way as it would be binded `InTransientScope`.

So you can have in your `global.asax`:

```
protected override Ninject.IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<RequestScopeObject>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    kernel.Bind<SingletonScopeObject>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
    return kernel;
}

protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    // init cache
    this.Kernel.Get<SingletonScopeObject>().Init();
}
```

But you will have to do cleanup after use of `RequestScopeObject` (e.g. `Dispose()` it, if it implements `IDisposable`).

```
public class SingletonScopeObject
{
    private string cache;
    private RequestScopeObject requestScopeObject;
    public SingletonScopeObject(RequestScopeObject requestScopeObject)
    {
        this.requestScopeObject = requestScopeObject;
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        cache = this.requestScopeObject.GetData();
        // do cleanup
        this.requestScopeObject.Dispose();
        this.requestScopeObject = null;
    }

    public string GetCache()
    {
        return cache;
    }
}
```

**Another approach**

Bind your `RequestScopeObject` both `InRequestScope` and `InSingletonScope` utilizing the conditional binding like this:

```
kernel.Bind<SingletonScopeObject>()
      .ToSelf()
      .InSingletonScope()
      .Named("singletonCache");
// as singleton for initialization
kernel.Bind<RequestScopeObject>()
      .ToSelf()
      .WhenParentNamed("singletonCache")
      .InSingletonScope();
// per request scope binding
kernel.Bind<RequestScopeObject>()
      .ToSelf()
      .InRequestScope();
```

The cleanup after initialization remains the same.

Comment: Is that "will probably" what worries me :)

Comment: I have changed "will probably" to "will definitely" with some explanation. ;-) However, you can try the second approach, which is more obvious (without unnecessary insight into Ninject source code).

Comment: the second approach is more sound. I will try it. Thanks :)